# The picture shown on google search

Tags: google-search

When I googled my website on mobile, google showed the picture next to my website. The picture is on my site, but I want another picture to be shown. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate to Google which image you'd like used for your property using Schema.org markup. Here's a quick company website example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context" : "http://schema.org",
 "@type" : "Organization",  
  "name" : "Example Company",
  "url" : "https://www.example.org", 
  "logo": "https://www.example.org/images/my-logo.png" }
</script>
```